# Command line script run in background goes in stopped state

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, shell, php

I have a short php utility script, I run it from cli simply with:

```
php myscript.php
```

The script is always running, periodically performing some tasks (not relevant for the question). It doesn't need any input from the user.
After running it, I usually press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> and then run `bg` to put the process in background, and everything is fine.

If I run it as:

```
php myscript.php &
```

the script is put on background on start, but it is also put in a stopped state. Example:

```
[1] 11513
[1]+  Stopped                 php myscript.php
```

even running `bg` at this point doesn't help, I have to run `fg`, then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> and `bg` again to make it work.

This is the php script:

```
<?
while(true){
    echo 'hi '.time()."\n";
    sleep(30);
}
?>
```

My problem is that I cannot run it directly in background, because the system stops it, and I don't understand why. How can I fix this?

**update:**

I made a bash version of the same script, and it can be run and put in background (running and **not stopped**) just by launching it with the & in the end (`script.sh &`)

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    echo `date`
    sleep 30
done
```

Why the php script is being stopped after launching it in background, and the bash script doesn't?
What could cause this different behaviour?

Comment: it'd be nice to know the reason from the user who voted to close the question

Comment: First, this has no apparent connection to professional system administration. Second, you said that your script's tasks are "not relevant for the question" but it is quite obvious that they are relevant and should have been described.

Comment: Why should it be *obvious*? If I say it isn't relevant, it **isn't**: the script just contains a while(true) with a sleep :) Btw, I added it to my question, so it can help to understand how (not) relevant it is. For the purposes of the question, is not relevant what tasks it'll perform. It's connected directly with a professional system administration, because I use this scripts in one of my linux servers (backup purposes, to add some detail).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, the process what do you send to background with the `&` and the script waiting for an input from the terminal, going into the stopped state.

E.g. have a bash script `valecho`:

```
#!/bin/sh
read val
echo $val
```

runnig it as:

```
./valecho &
```

the script will stop.

When run it as

```
echo hello | ./valecho &
```

will correctly run and finish.

So, check your php - probably wants some input from the `stdin`

**Edit** - based on comment:

i'm not an php developer - but just tried the next script (`p.php`)

```
<?php
    while(true){
        echo 'hi '.time()."\n";
        sleep(3);
    }
?>
```

with the command:

```
php -f p.php &
```

and running nicely... so... sry for confusion...

Comment: thank you, but I don't think this could be the case because the script doesn't wait for any user input. You can see the code in my question, it's very short. Also, if I put it in foreground and then background without inserting any input, it works.. how can this be?

Comment: @LorenzoMarcon see edit - works for me... (having only default php installation)

Comment: thanks again, the problem is that on my pc it works to me as well, but on the server it doesn't.. I'm investigating on the differences

Comment: @LorenzoMarcon - only a tip: `set_time_limit(0);` ?

Comment: I found what was causing the problem, and wrote an answer. Since you gave me the right input (readline) I'll give you the accepted answer :) Thanks!

Comment: @LorenzoMarcon Thank you - and enjoy your script. ;)

Answer (score 20):

I found what is causing the issue. In PHP, if the readline module is enabled, any command line script will expect an input, even if the script is written to NOT wait for user input.

To check if you have readline support enabled, just run:

```
php --info |grep "Readline Support"
```

and check the output. If you get `Readline Support => enabled` then you have readline enabled and you may experience the problem described in the original question.

The proper way to use the cli when is then to explicitly specify that php is not using the terminal for input:

```
php myscript.php < /dev/null &
```

Further info: http://php.net/manual/en/book.readline.php

Alternatives:

```
./test.php >/dev/null &
```

or (more creative):

```
nohup php test.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

(p.s.: I still believe this question belongs to ServerFault, btw.. problem solved!)

Comment: I have the same issue. My PHP is from yum and not compiled; how can I disable `readline`?

Comment: did you try to remove the package php-readline (if installed)?

Comment: `php myscript.php < /dev/null &` solved this for me, thanks for the readline explanation

Answer (score 0):

From http://php.net/manual/en/book.readline.php :

When readline is enabled, php switches the terminal mode to accept line-buffered input. This means that the proper way to use the cli when you pipe to an interactive command is to explicitly specify that php is not using the terminal for input:

```
php myscript.php < /dev/null &
```

[source](http://shtuff.it/article/20/Send-a-php-cli-task-to-the-background)